# How to implement a double sided referral program with Stripe Checkout?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

we're selling access to our product which has a monthly/yearly subscription. We're using Stripe Checkout to manage our subscriptions. How do I implement double sided rewards for our users (e.g. if a friend signs up with someone's promo code, they both get $25 off the price of their subscription).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want to have PromotionCodes being linked to unique Customers in Stripe, which is something you would track on your end. Like promo_123 and promo_456 are related to cus_2.

Then, if cus_1 redeems a PromotionCode that was linked to cus_2, that PromotionCode applies to cus_1's Subscription and reduces the amount due on the Subscription's Invoice for cus_1.

Once that Subscription is created and PromotionCode redeemed, you would create a -$25 InvoiceItem [0] on cus_2 to give them a discount on their next Invoice.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/create

Comment: This is very helpful! Quick question–how do I determine a subscription is created and a PromotionCode is redeemed (so I can then create a -$25 InvoiceItem on cus_2)?

Comment: You listen to the `customer.subscription.created` webhook event. Fetch the Subscription in that event and "expand" the discounts.promotion_code field like `expand: ['discounts.promotion_code']` and that will get you the PromotionCode used on the subscription. Then you can run any other logic to add an InvoiceItem to the other Customer.

Comment: @hmunoz thanks for this insight ! I am trying to implement the same thing, but a question came up: if you generate promo code for each user so that they can share it with other users, how do you prevent this user from applying the promo code on its own subscription??